# How to change all the strings in an iphone application with respective selected language in settings?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, translation, locale, nslocalizedstring

I need help from you, I need to display all the text, labels , strings and what ever text is showing to user in the iphone application with respective selected language in settings of iphone.

for example user selects German or French in settings of iPhone language, then my application should provide or view the details in that language.

I need sample code for localization, Is there any simple way to follow the standard steps to translate the code to different languages in iphone sdk.

please healp me, I hope that I can get efficient solution on this from you.

Thank you,
Madan Mohan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here: http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/iphone-applications-localization-guide/

Comment: I have already seen this site, I want resource code to localization.

Answer (score 0):

I think the previous link gives a pretty good idea of how to do I18N on the iPhone, but if you feel you need more info, you can try this article http://blog.federicomestrone.com/2010/05/18/internationalise-your-iphone-apps-with-xcode/ which is just slightly more code-orientated.

The point though is always the same - you have to separate code from text resources and load all your text (strings) with the *NSLocalizedString* macro, or a variant thereof.